# Simulating property changes with immutable objects

Tags: java, immutability

After searching I found these questions, but no answers to my specific question:

[Undo/Redo with immutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812978/undo-redo-with-immutable-objects)

[Why continue to use getters with immutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272425/why-continue-to-use-getters-with-immutable-objects)

[How to write a test friendly immutable value class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223337/how-to-write-a-test-friendly-immutable-value-class/13225260#13225260)

[Is it okay to expose the state of an immutable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910769/is-it-okay-to-expose-the-state-of-an-immutable-object/21942405#21942405)

Here's the setup:
I've got an immutable class like so:

```
public class MyImmutableOb {
    private final String name;
    private final Collection<Integer> myNumbers;

    public MyImmutableOb(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        myNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public MyImmutableOb(String name, MyImmutableOb oldOb) {
        this.name = name;
        myNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i : oldOb.getNumbers()) myNumbers.add(i);
    }

    public Collection<Integer> getNumbers() {
        return new LinkedList<>(myNumbers);
    }
}
```

I have included a constructor like this, meant to allow simulating a name change on the object. The question is, does reproducing the `Collection` in this fashion break immutability?:

```
public MyImmutableOb(String name, MyImmutableOb oldOb) {
    this.name = name;
    myNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i : oldOb.getNumbers()) myNumbers.add(i);
}
```

I am having a tough time wrapping my head around this one.

Comment: The `myNumbers` member of your 'immutable' class is a _mutable_ list.  Your class either is or is not _effectively_ immutable.  The answer depends on whether or not anything in the `// and so on...` part of the class modifies the list.

Comment: Your second constructor calls `oldOb.getNumbers()`, but you did not show us the definition of getNumbers().  What does it do?  If it merely returns `oldOb.myNumbers`, then your class is mutable:  A client could call getNumbers(), and then modify the list.

Comment: That definition might help, huh? Haha, my bad, I went ahead and added the definition in. Those are all the methods in the class currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, in order to make instances of your class *immutable*, you have to explicity write immutability into your class; object types (as opposed to primitive types) are *mutable* by nature. The collections classes in `java.util` are of course mutable. Java classes like `String` and the primitive boxing types `Integer`, `Double`, etc., are written to be immutable.

Your variable declaration

```
private final String name;
```

is immutable because it is declared `final` *and* because `String` objects are immutable.

Using the `final` keyword for a variable ensures that the variable can be assigned a value only once, therefore it is an excellent tool for designing an immutable class. However, it is not enough, because if the variable is assigned to a mutable object then the variables in *that* object can still be modified.

Your variable declaration

```
private final Collection<int> myNumbers;
```

does not guarantee immutability because, although `myNumbers` can be assigned only once, the collection assigned to it is still mutable.

The good news is, the Java `Collections` utility class provides lightweight wrappers to make your collections immutable. This will require a change to your first constructor

```
public MyImmutableOb(String name, int... numbers) {
    this.name = name;
    this.myNumbers = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(numbers));
}
```

so that `myNumbers` is now truly immutable. Note I've forsaken your usage of `LinkedList`, because there's no point in using that specialized `List` implementation when it's immutable within `MyImmutableOb`.

Thus your second constructor becomes

```
public MyImmutableOb(String name, MyImmutableOb oldOb) {
    this.name = name;
    this.myNumbers = oldOb.myNumbers;
}
```

because `oldOb`'s `myNumbers` is already immutable, so there's no point in copying.

In closing, I realize you probably did want to be able to change the contents of `myNumbers` after construction of a `MyImmutableOb`. Obviously, making the class truly immutable implies that nothing can change in its instances after construction.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that you got rid of the `LinkedList`. For clarification, `LinkedList` was being used because the order of the items being stored matters. Thanks why I used it. Thanks for the in depth explanation, it is appreciated!